# Can i replace the system DLLs in Symbian?

Tags: symbian

all DLLs and EXEs in Symbian goes to sys\bin folder, right?
does system DLLs (build-in DLLs) in there too?
can i replace while install my own app?
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried that you write over some system DLL by mistake then the recommended approach is to add you application's UID to the name of the DLL and EXE files, i.e. Calendar_20005ab12.EXE.

Otherwise there is quite a big chance to have conflict with some existing app, especially if you want to write your version of some popular application.

Answer (score 0):

They do go there, but you can't replace them from a normal process because of the strict security model Symbian employs.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes.
Some system DLLs and EXEs are protected and cannot be replaced. 
For all the others you need to match the security permissions of the DLL or EXE or risk the stability of the device.

In general I'd say that you don't want to do this unless you are the original author of a executable.